# Insert Into query running for 7+hrs on a table having ~450+million records

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, sqlperformance

Database:- Oracle 19c Standard edition on AWS

we are trying to Insert around 450 million records from Table A into Table B using the below query

<insert into table a  (col1,col2,col3,col4,...,col31 in)
select col1,col2,col3,col4,...,col31 in from table b;>

this query is been executing for 7+hrs.

we checked the V$session_longops around 6hrs ago (03.30 am IST) and it was showing a remaining time of around 288 mins with a ~17% completion rate.
when we are checking it now it shows 280 mins as time remaining after 7+ hrs

We have made all indexes unusable as well on the table.

the DBA team is also monitoring and doesn't see any resource crunch or tablespace issues.

is there a way to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have constraints on the table you are inserting into?

Comment: Yes we do have. constraints on them,

Comment: If the constraints are more complicated than `not null`, you might be able to make the constraints unvalidated to improve performance.

Comment: Depending on how many CPU's you have, try employing some parallelism. Also, you can run direct path (use the APPEND hint ).